# What is wrong with this code? It is showing the output correctly but ending with exit status 56. what does it mean?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char n;
  int a;
  scanf("%s",&n);
  if(isdigit(n))
  {
    a=atoi(&n);
    if(a%2==0)
    {
      printf("EVEN"); 
    }
    else
    {
      printf("ODD");
    }
  }
  else
    printf("not a number");
}
```

it is showing an exit status 56 error along with the output. The question is to print given input is even or odd or it's not a number using nested if loop

Comment: While an explicit `return` isn't needed in `main` in newer versions of C, it was needed in older version. Your compiler must not support the newer version.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&n);` That is a buffer overflow. `%s` stores a string which is a NUL terminated sequence of characters. `n` is only one byte so can only store an empty string. Any input more than that will overflow the buffer. Change `n` to a larger array like `char n[10];`

Comment: use ```scanf("%c", &n)```

Comment: What are your OS, platform, compiler, IDE, etc...? BTW what _exactly_ is the program supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You never return a value from `main`, so you invoke undefined behaviour and end up with an arbitrary return value. You should enable your compiler's warnings as it should warn about this.

In newer versions of C, a `return 0;` is implied for `main`. Your compiler does not appear to support this version of C.

---

As an aside, note that your program suffers from a buffer overflow. You allocate but a single character for the string to read in, which is too small for any useful input since the string-terminating NUL requires one character.

You need to use a large buffer. Even then, you'd need to add some protection against reading more than the buffer can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Your `int main()` function is not explicitly returning any value, you have to return a value with the desired exit code at the end of your main function (or wherever you'd like to if you want to exit due to an error), you need to:

```
int main( void )
{
    // your code here...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // EXIT_SUCCESS => 0 (contained in stdlib.h)
}
```

you can also use these exit code macros to exit your program due to an error

```
int main( void )
{
    int *ptr = calloc( 10, sizeof( *ptr ) );
    
    if( ptr == NULL )
    {
        puts("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // or return EXIT_FAILURE; since you are in main function
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and btw, your using a `char` variable to read a string, you should use `%c` in `scanf` since you are reading a single character

```
scanf("%c", &n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors. Among other things, your code cannot give a 100% accurate result due to incorrect use of the isdigit() and atoi () functions. The isdigit() function works with a character, and the atoi() function works with a string. Depending on your conditions, there are several types of implementation.
According to the rules of the C language, the atoi( ) function returns a number-the result of converting a string if there is a number at the beginning of the string. If there is a non-digit character at the beginning of the string, the function returns zero.   If the number in the string exceeds the maximum or minimum size of an int number, the function returns the maximum or minimum allowed number for the int type, respectively. The returned value depends on the hardware platform on which the program is running.
It differs from the atol () function by the type of the returned number and, as a result, the maximum long string to be converted. For atoi() , the returned number is of the int type, and, accordingly, the bit depth is 16 or 32 bits, depending on the hardware platform on which the program is running. For atol() , the returned number is of the long int type, which is always 32-bit, regardless of the processor architecture.
In accordance with this, I propose the following implementation of your task:

```
#include<ctype.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char n[10]; 
int a; 
scanf("%9s",n);
if((a=atoi(n))!=0)
{
    if(a%2==0) 
    { 
    printf("EVEN"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    printf("ODD"); 
    } 
} 
else 
    printf("not a number");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int containsOnlyDigits(char s[100], int len)
{
    int i, flag;
    char ch;
    flag = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            continue;
        flag = 0;
    }
    return flag;
}
int main()
{
    char s[100];
    int len, n;
    scanf("%s", &s);
    len = strlen(s);
    if (containsOnlyDigits(s, len))
    {
        n = atoi(s);
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            printf("Even");
        else
            printf("Odd");
    }
    else
        printf("Not a number");
return 0;
```

Comment: Please don't just provide code without any explanations.